# Any code examples for making a Rails 3 controller a WebDAV server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webdav

I need to implement a dynamic WebDAV server that authenticates users against users in a Rails 3 database and which saves files uploaded via WebDAV into the database. Is there any code out there that does this and that can serve as an example?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034384/rails-3-1-app-with-integrated-webdav-and-authentication ) .

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the sources of https://github.com/georgi/rack_dav, it's doing exactly that.