# Rails 3.1 app with integrated webdav and authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, webdav

I would like to enable WebDav for Rails 3.1 application, where I use Devise for authentication and CanCan for authorization.

So far I turned on WebDav and works fine. Is it possible to use Devise logins/users with dav4rack to enable/restrict access to certain files/directories on WebDav? Maybe there is already a howto or wiki page about that? Any help will be appreciated.

PS. is this the right way of solving this kind of problem? maybe i should switch back to apache mod_dav and synchronise apache's dav users/groups with users/groups defined in my Rails application?

Comment: What did you end up with?

Comment: Id didn't have enough time to deal with it so as far as I remember I moved quickly to SoGo (php), which provided me with some additional features.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of Devise w/ a Dav4Rack resource here
https://github.com/bryanrite/dav4rack-example-devise-subdirectories/blob/master/app/models/my_resource.rb

```
class MyResource < DAV4Rack::FileResource

  def root
    File.join(options[:root].to_s, user.id.to_s)
  end

  private

  def authenticate(username, password)
    self.user = User.find_by_username(username)
    user.try(:valid_password?, password)
  end  

end
```

In my case, I used email instead of username.